# My menu is not working for some reason

Tags: java

```
Scanner scn =new Scanner(System.in);
int Choice =  scn.nextInt();

do
{
// Display Menu
System.out.println("*** MENU ***");
System.out.println("1. Register Member");
System.out.println("2. Rent Books");
System.out.println("3. View Member and Rental Information");
System.out.println("4. Exit");

        switch(Choice)
        {
            case 1 : {
                       System.out.println("M");
                     }break;
            case 2 : {
                        System.out.println("\n\n2. View All Students & Marks");                            
                     }break;
            case 3 : {
                      System.out.println("\n\n3. Search for Student");
                     }break;
            case 4 : {
                        System.out.println("choice4");
                     }break;                
            default :{
                        System.err.println("\nInvalid Menu Option");
                     }break; 
            }          
    }while(Choice !=4);
  } 
}
```

The output of it will return blank and when a number is pressed it will loop forever I tried arranging the outline of the spaces many times but still didn't work I'm trying to make the menu not exit unless the user chooses 4  carry out the other choices and re display the menu once the other function has been executed.

Comment: You input an int _before_ your loop, and then you loop until your int is 4. But nothing in your loop changes the value of your int, so if it is not 4, it will never be 4. Consider how you could input the int _inside_ your loop.

Comment: Unrelated: A) formatting matters - dont dump such a code mess on us B) names matter - read about java naming conventions and follow them. Variables go camelCase!

Answer (score 0):

Simple: you ask for user input **outside** of your loop.

Move that scanner request **into** the loop, like:

```
int choice;

do {
 ... print the menu
 choice =  scn.nextInt();
 switch(choice)
} while ...
```